# Very slow query for large table

Tags: mysql, sql

Although MySQL and queries are very fast in terms of execution, somehow mine is very slow.

Hardware:

- RAM => 8 GB
- Dual Core Processor
- Windows Server
- Task Manager: Memory 30%

Total Records in table = 16,83,410

Table Structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `test_result` (
  `parameter_id` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `parameter_value` varchar(5000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `test_id` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `package_id` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `client_id` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `added_by` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `added_on` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `modify_by` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `modify_on` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `test_result_status` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `analysis_comment` varchar(5000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `report_id` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`report_id`,`client_id`,`test_id`,`parameter_id`),
  KEY `ehr_test_result_index` (`report_id`,`client_id`,`test_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
```

Query:

```
SELECT parameter_id,parameter_value
FROM test_result 
WHERE client_id = 14274 and report_id = 266432 and test_id = 21;
```

So, I'm executing query against single table, time taken to exeucte = 16 seconds :(

When I re-run the query, it takes 4 seconds, and on the third 1 seconds
(looks like cache is being used or some sort of indexing)

How to optimize this query? Should I convert parameter_id, client_id, report_id, test_id to numeric type?

Comment: How many rows are being returned?  The query and the indexes look okay.

Comment: Please post results as text of SHOW INDEX FROM test_result 
  and EXPLAIN SELECT ...

Comment: It looks like this table was implemented by someone that wasn't aware of MySQL datatypes *other* than VARCHAR. If any of these columns are storing *integer* values within a range supported by MySQL integer datatypes, use an integer datatype for that column (BIGINT, INT, or SMALLINT.) Also seems like added_on and modify_on could be DATETIME datatype.

Comment: How selectable is the data?  What is the cardinality?  How many rows are you pulling back?  The second index is redundant, as the primary key has the fields in the right order.

Answer (score 0):

Indexing is absolutely the key. Numeric indexes are much more straightforward to process and the fields themselves are much smaller. You currently have:

```
`parameter_id` varchar(45)
`test_id` varchar(45)
`client_id` varchar(45)
`report_id` varchar(45)
```

That means each index field is 45 x 4 = 180 bytes! If you MUST store as text, that would come down to (for a typical numeric field equivalent to a 32-bit integer) 7 bytes. And of course storing as an actual 32-bit integer (INT) would be only 4 bytes. 4 x 4 = 16 bytes. That means ~ 1/10 as much to read to find the right values, plus the other optimizations associated with this being a simple integer rather than translating between numeric and text. I am sure it will make a **HUGE** difference in query time.

You also don't need the second index as the PRIMARY KEY includes everything in the second KEY in the same sequence.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, yes, ids should be integers, i'll check and confirm, thanks :)